# update manifest.json version using gitversion on commit

Tags: json, google-chrome, gitversion

I have a Google Chrome extension which has a manifest.json. Recently I started using gitversion, and I like it. Is there a way that I can smartly increment the version in my manifest.json whenever it changes in gitversion?

Comment: I came across this question searching for a programmatic way to update my google chrome extension manifest file.  I had never heard of gitversion and am curious, why are you using it seems like semvar is only required for package maintainers and not necessarily for final extension/app projects.  What is gitversion providing for you?

Comment: I have a bunch of other tools and packages in the same repo that use it in CI.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing out of the box in GitVersion that will do that for you today.  The only files that are automatically updated are AssemblyInfo files.  There is nothing to stop you running GitVersion, grabbing the resulting JSON output, and using the asserted variables to then update the .json file through another means.  For instance, if you have a build script, you could do just that.

Have a look at this blog post for an example on how you can do this in PowerShell:

http://jake.ginnivan.net/blog/2014/05/25/simple-versioning-and-release-notes/

Copied here with the consent of @jakeginnivan

```
$currentDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$output = . "$currentDir\GitVersion.1.0.0.0\tools\GitVersion.exe"

$joined = $output -join "`n"
$versionInfo = $joined | ConvertFrom-Json
$version = $versionInfo.SemVer

mkdir "$currentDir\Artifacts"

Copy-Item "$currentDir\src\UsefulStuff.psm1" "$currentDir\Artifacts\UsefulStuff.psm1"

(Get-Content "$currentDir\Artifacts\UsefulStuff.psm1") | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '__version__',"v$version"} |
    Out-File "$currentDir\Artifacts\UsefulStuff.psm1"

Write-Output "##teamcity[buildNumber '$version']"
```